# Vuetify v-data-table custom filter for dropdown

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-data-table that already has the :search and :sort-by enabled. I have now created a select where I pull in my status from VueX. Accepted, Rejected. What I want to do is not only search or sort but when selecting from the drop down, accepted only the accepted values display in the table.

```html
<v-select
    v-model="selectStatus"
    label="Status"
    :items="statusData"
    item-value="id"
    item-text="name"
    return-object
    @change="filterStatus"
/>
```

Is this the correct way to setup the filter?

```js
methods: {
    filterStatus () {
      console.log('This is where I am planning to add my custom filter')
    }
}
```

This is my statusData:

```js
userStatus : [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "Accepted",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: " Rejected",
  },
];
```

Or better to pass in the data:

```
{ text: 'Status', value: 'status.name', filter: value => {}},
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable certain values to be selected add a `disabled` property to your items.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    items: [{
        id: 0,
        name: 'Accepted'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: ' Rejected',
        disabled: true
      }
    ],
    value: null
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      Value : {{value}}
      <v-select
          v-model="value"
          label="Status"
          :items="items"
          item-value="id"
          item-text="name"
          return-object
        />
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Documentation : [props-disabled](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-disabled)

Comment: This isnt what I was asking at all, sorry. Looking how to filter